# Docker - Cannot ping after switching from Windows to Linux container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

We have a docker compose file which allow us to ping container IP (from Windows host to container) when using Windows container.

```
version: '3'

services:
  netcorewebapplication1:
    image: netcorewebapplication1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: NetCoreWebApplication1/Dockerfile
## Windows
    networks:
      nat:
        ipv4_address: 172.30.235.10
networks:
  nat:
    external: true
```

But after switching to Linux container, we cannot ping to the container IP

```
version: '3'

services:
  netcorewebapplication1:
    image: netcorewebapplication1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: NetCoreWebApplication1/Dockerfile
## Linux user defined bridge network
    networks:
      my_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.30.235.10
networks:
  my_net:
    external: true
```

Why is not possible to ping or browse the Linux container IP address?

Comment: Not sure if this is configured differently between Win/Linux, but you might need to define the subnet using an `ipam` config in your top-level networks setting: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ipv4_address-ipv6_address

Comment: I have noticed once you switch from Windows to Linux container, `docker network ls` won't show the driver `nat`. That is one difference. I have created manually a bridge network for this linux container. I can ping from linux (172.30.x.x) to windows host (192.168.x.x) but cannot do the opposite. Not sure if this linux container has a firewall running or if a setting is missing in Windows (routes?). Linux kernel version: 4.9.60-linuxkit-aufs GNU/Linux, debian version 9.3. Windows host is 10 Version 10.0.16299.125 (firewall off)